# Trying to find a scalar potential for a vector field whose domain is not connected or to prove it is not conservative

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $U=\mathbb{R}^2-\lbrace(x,y)|xy+1=0 \rbrace$ and let $F:U \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined as $F(x,y)=(\frac{1-y^2}{(1+xy)^2},\frac{1-x^2}{(1+xy)^2})$

I am trying to find a scalar potential of $F$ in $U$ if it exists or to prove that it doesn't exist. I've computed its curl and is zero but the problem is that the function is not defined in the two-pieces curve $y=- \frac{1}{x}$, so I can't just conclude the field is conservative because of its curl being zero. In this case it doesn't seem I can proceed by taking some closed curve whose interior contains some point which is not in the domain of $F$, then compute the circulation over that curve and get a non-zero result to conclude $F$ is not conservative because the curve itself will contain some points where $F$ is not defined. So I tryied to directly find a potential for $F$ (or something that tells me that ootential doesn't exist) by taking the antiderivatives with respect to $x$ of the first component function of $F$ and with respect to $y$ of the second component function of $F$.

Sumarizing: I've assumed there is some function $f$ such that $\nabla f=F$ and under this hipotesis I got (by the process of integrating the $F$ components): $$f(x,y)=\frac{y^2-1}{xy^2+y}+g(y)=\frac{x^2-1}{yx^2+x}+h(x)$$
However, I've tryied to find some $g$ and $h$ functions that make that equality hold and I failed, I also tryied to realize if from that expression I could deduce shuch $g$ and $h$ functions can't exist and also failed. Intuitively it seems to me there are no such $g$ and $h$ functions but I can't deduce a formal argument to prove it.

Is this the right way to go or what else can I try, I'm kind of lost here, I've just learned Green's theorem and some basic stuffs of divergence and curl.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the question of whether or not this vector field really is conservative, you’ve jumped the gun a bit by integrating both components of the field. Starting with the $x$-component, you’ve found that $f(x,y)={y^2-1\over xy^2+y}+g(y)$. You should now differentiate this with respect to $y$ and set this equal to the $y$-component of $F$ to get an expression for $g'(y)$, which you can then integrate to get $g$, and so also $f$.

An alternative method that can be used if the vector field is defined in a star-shaped region centered on the origin (and can be adapted to any star-shaped region) is to compute the integral $$f(x,y)=\int_0^1 F(tx,ty)\cdot\langle x,y\rangle\,dt.$$ This can sometimes be easier than the alternating integration and differentiation above and gets you an answer all at once. The functions found by these two methods may differ by a constant of integration.